# The plugin `flutter_bluetooth_basic` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter, printing, bluetooth-printing

**HI i got an error  when i want user Bluetooth printer in flutter **
i took  https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration. but didn't work

The plugin `flutter_bluetooth_basic` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

void _testPrint(PrinterBluetooth printer) async {
printerManager.selectPrinter(printer);

```
const PaperSize paper = PaperSize.mm80;
final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();

// TEST PRINT
// final PosPrintResult res =
// await printerManager.printTicket(await testTicket(paper));

// DEMO RECEIPT
final res =
    await printerManager.printTicket((await demoReceipt(paper, profile)));

showToast(res.msg);
```

}